# Launch ViewController from AppDelegate, tabbar missing from bottom

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I am developing my first app, where I am trying to manage a session in my app, where I am trying to check if user has logged in recently. If user has logged in recently, then I want to skip login page, and move him to next page.
Here what I am doing, however I am unable to proceed forward

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
       let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewControllerB = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("account") as! AccountDetails
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewControllerB)
    let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = viewControllerB
    let vc = self.window?.rootViewController

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return true
}
```

I am  able to get to the desired view,but the Tabbar on that view is missng. I want to restore the same.

Second Screen (My Account which I want to show)

```
 class AccountDetails: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            // Initialize Tab Bar Item
            tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Account Details", image: UIImage(named: "Account.png"), tag: 1)

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working solution

```
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewControllerB = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabbar") as! UITabBarController
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewControllerB)
    let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = viewControllerB
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

//tabbar is the storyboard ID of tabbarcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line `self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

with

```
self.window?.rootViewController = navController
```

Comment: it didnot help either

Answer (score 0):

Change window's rootViewController:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    if(User loggin last time) {
        let yourTargetViewController = UIViewController()
        yourTargetViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.window?.rootViewController = yourTargetViewController
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: sorry it didnot help me :(